# require.js not working with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, requirejs

I was using require.js with an ASP.NET site and everything was working fine.  Now I'm trying to do it in an MVC site and I can't seem to get it working.  My _layout.cshtml file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/toastr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/percentage")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body style="background-image: url('/Content/images/background.png')">

...abbreviated...

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/require")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/percentage")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/placeholder")

    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
```

and then I have an index.cshtml file as such:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hobby Matrix -- Home";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/Scripts/helpers/home"></script>
}
```

and my home.js file is like this:

```
    define([], function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('here');
    });

})
```

But for some reason, my alert is never getting called when I go to that view (index.cshtml).  Clearly I assume I'm doing something wrong related to how MVC processes these files, but I can't figure out what.  When I view source, all the lines of code I expect have been rendered and I get no error.  I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem had nothing to do with require.js -- this was working just fine.  The problem was that I was missing a "/" in my ajax call, so it wasn't finding the "controller/action" that my ajax call was trying to get to.  It was working on the one page, which was in the same path, but on the second page which isn't, it couldn't resolve where I was pointing to.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at RequireJS for ASP.NET MVC template project, the integration is explain [here](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2012/09/intro-requirejs-for-asp-net-mvc/), you can fork the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/stefanprodan/RequireJSDotNet).

Comment: I've looked at that and it seems way more complicated than what I'm trying to do. I'm pretty sure I don't need to do all that stuff for what I'm trying to accomplish.